# construct a matrix by removing different elements from an array without loops in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

Given a vector `X` of discrete positive integers with size 160*1, and a table `Tb1` in size 40*200, that contains a list of indices to be deleted from `X` Each column from the 200 columns in `Tb1` points to 40 elements to be deleted from original `X`.

I create a new matrix of the remaining 120*200 elements by using a `for` loop with 200 iterations, that at round `i` deletes 40 elements from a copy of the original `X` according to the indices listed in `Tb1(:,i)`, but it takes too much time and memory.

How can I get the result without using loops and with a minimum number of operations?

Comment: I can't see how do you get a matrix by removing something from an array

Comment: Please elaborate on your question, add sample code, and clarify on the previous comment on how the array becomes a matrix.

Comment: Seems like the answer below suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

Here are different methods:

Method1:

```
idx = ~hist(tbl, 1:160);
[f,~]=find(idx);
result1 = reshape(M(f),120,200);
```

Method2:

```
idx = ~hist(tbl, 1:160);
M2=repmat(M,200,1);
result2 = reshape(M2(idx),120,200);
```

Method 3 & 4:

```
% idx can be generated using accumarray
idx = ~accumarray([tbl(:) reshape(repmat(1:200,40,1),[],1)],true,[160,200],@any);
%... use method 1 and 2
```

Method5:

```
M5=repmat(M,200,1);
M5(bsxfun(@plus,tbl,0:160:160*199))=[];
result5 = reshape(M5,120,200);
```

Assuming that `M` is an array of integers and `tbl` is the table of indices.

It can be tested with the following data:

```
M = rand(160,1);
[~,tbl] = sort(rand(160,200));
tbl = tbl(1:40,:);
```

However it is more efficient if you generate indices of elements to be remained instead of indices of elements to be removed.